# Front-End Entry (Guest) saving correct values on error

Tags: form, guest-entries

I'm building a Guest Entry Form, and one of the fields is a dropdown. Everything feeds through fine, but if one of the other fields has a validation error, I can save any inputted data with the code as outlined in the [Entry Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form)

```
<input id="customField" type="text" name="fields[customField]"
{%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.customField }}"{% endif -%}>
```

But, with the dropdown, I can't get the value to stick, it always defaults to the first option (It's to grab a name title - eg, Mr. Mrs, Miss etc) on an error:

```
<select name="fields[honorific]">
    {% for honortitle in entry.honorific.options %}
        <option {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ honortitle.value }}{% endif -%}">{% if entry is defined %}{{ honortitle.value }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

So, if I've already selected the option at the bottom of the list, how do I get the field to remember what I've selected if there's an error elsewhere?

Thanks, Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into a past solution for checkboxes thanks to @bradbell, here's the answer!

```
 <select name="fields[honorific]">
     {% for honortitle in entry.honorific.options %}
         {% set chosen = false %}

         {% if honortitle.selected %}
             {% set chosen = true %}
         {% endif %}

         <option value="{{ honortitle.value }}"{% if chosen %} selected{% endif %}>{{ honortitle.label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```